# how to save a matrix to a file in matlab

Tags: file, matlab, matrix, octave

I a doing a program in Octave that multiplies a lot of matrices. All the matrices are stores in a cell matrix. where:

```
cell(index,1) is the matrix in the left
cell(index,2) is the matrix in the right
cell(index,3) is the result.
```

I want to save a lot of matrices in this way in a file, example:

```
cell(index,1) cell(index,2) = cell(index,3) 
cell(index,1) cell(index,2) = cell(index,3)
cell(index,1) cell(index,2) = cell(index,3)
```

and so on.

I know that there exists a function `dlmwrite`, but I don't know exactly how to use it (I am new in octave) so that I can have this format.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to do this. If you are only ever going to use this in matlab, use the save command. `save filename.dat cell`. This is loaded by `read filename.dat` If you are wanting them to be readable, say, by a string, use the `cell2mat` command.

In your case, I believe you are actually wanting to print out the values to the screen, or to a file. Either method is almost identical, if you do it the right way in matlab. This is the general idea:

```
for index=1:size(cell,1)
  fprintf("%i %i = %i\n",cell(index,1),cell(index,2),cell(index,3));
end
```

To print to a file is very similar

```
fid=fopen("somefile.txt","w")
for index=1:size(cell,1)
  fprintf(fid,"%i %i = %i\n",cell(index,1),cell(index,2),cell(index,3));
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: but if I do save file.txt cell, then it saves the cell in the other way like:

Comment: But if I do save file.txt cell, then it saves the cell in the other way like:                                                                 matrix1                                                             matrix2                                                             matrix3                                                              And I dont want that. If I Use the cell2mat command, how I can format this in the way that I want?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you are wanting now. Take a look at my latest edit.

Comment: fid = fopen(myfile,"w");                                      fprintf(fid,"%i %i = %i",cell(index,1),cell(index,2),cell(index,3)); Is the way to save it in a file? is just that it is not saving it... How is the correct way to print to a file?